# Python subprocess: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm running a Minecraft server under subprocess to use the output in a python script.

```
mc_dir = 'C:\\Users\\aiche\\Desktop\\server'
mc_start_cmd = 'java -Xms1G -Xmx1G -jar server.jar --nogui'
server = subprocess.Popen(mc_start_cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, cwd=mc_dir)
```

But when I Start the Server I'm getting this Log:

```
Starting net.minecraft.server.Main
2022-08-11 10:52:19,591 ServerMain ERROR Unable to delete file C:\Users\aiche\Desktop\server\logs\latest.log: java.nio.file.FileSystemException C:\Users\aiche\Desktop\server\logs\latest.log: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
[10:52:21] [ServerMain/INFO]: Building unoptimized datafixer
[10:52:21] [ServerMain/INFO]: Environment: authHost='https://authserver.mojang.com/', accountsHost='https://api.mojang.com/', sessionHost='https://sessionserver.mojang.com/', servicesHost='https://api.minecraftservices.com/', name='PROD'
[10:52:21] [ServerMain/ERROR]: Failed to start the minecraft server
java.io.IOException: The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file
at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write(FileDispatcherImpl.java:68) ~[?:?]
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:132) ~[?:?]
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:76) ~[?:?]
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:67) ~[?:?]
at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.write(FileChannelImpl.java:288) ~[?:?]
at alo.a(SourceFile:40) ~[server-1.19.2.jar:?]
at drq$c.<init>(SourceFile:333) ~[server-1.19.2.jar:?]
at drq.c(SourceFile:321) ~[server-1.19.2.jar:?]
at net.minecraft.server.Main.main(SourceFile:125) ~[server-1.19.2.jar:?]
at net.minecraft.bundler.Main.lambda$run$0(Main.java:54) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) [?:?]
```

Why cant't the server.jar use the files and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you confirm (with Task Manager for example) that no other Minecraft server is running on the same machine? Does rebooting the machine help?

Comment: check your task manager to see if you don't have another minecraft server running in the background. Also, if you have the logfile open in another application close that application. As Wander said, rebooting is likely going to fix it (the hardhanded way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rebooted the machine and it worked just fine.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Answers (and questions) should be written such that future users can learn from them, too. Please either [edit] this answer to provide details about what was wrong, or consider deleting your question entirely (I think you'll have to delete this answer first).